# PHP How to insert NULL in Database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a normal HTML-File that give a string via. POST to my PHP-file wich will put this to a MySQL-database.

How do I achieve that I can write a "real" `NULL` in the database and not " " (a empty string) or something like that?

The MySQL column is nullable.

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="putInDatabase.php">

    <label>Text</label>
    <textarea name="text" ></textarea>

    <label>Picture URL (optional)</label>
    <input name="image" />
    <br>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

My PHP-File:

```
<?php

  $text = "";
  $image = null;

  if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
    $text = $_POST["text"];

    $image = $_POST["image"];
  }

  $text = strtr ($text, array ('"' => '\"'));


  $con = mysql_connect("censored :)");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('ERROR' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("_DATABASE_HERE_", $con);


  $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO `_DATABASE_HERE_`.`_NAME_HERE_` (`Text`, `PictureURL`) VALUES ('$text', '$image ');";  

  $res = mysql_query($insertSQL); 
  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  mysql_close($con);

  echo "Success!";

?>
```

Comment: Are you entering the word NULL in your form element?

Comment: first you need to make sure that the column is set as nullable ,if it does you can just write NULL on the insert statement.

Comment: you need to switch to `PDO` or `MySQLi` prepared statements!!!

Comment: Instead of using the `mysql` functions, use PDO with prepared statements.  This article will show you all you need to know how to do it the right way from the start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I add a URL in my "Image" form element. But I want to set it NULL if the user don't write anything in that element.

Comment: Use a conditional statement then and use NULL as a "string" in the value. A ternary operator can also be used.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 - the accepted answer shows how NULLs can be easily inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to pre-process your text. And since you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) this should be considered MANDATORY:

```
if (isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text'])) {
   $safetext = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']) . "'";
} else {
   $safetext = 'null';
}

$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ($safetext, ...)";
```

Note how the quotes are added inside the `if()`. If there's some text to be done, the sql-escaped text is surrounded by quotes. if there's no text at all, then the string `null` is added in. This boils down to the difference between `null` and `'null'`.

`null` is an sql null, "unknown value". `'null'` is a string with the literal characters `n`, `u`, `l`, and `l` in it. In SQL terms, they're two completely different things.

The above code would produce

```
INSERT ... VALUES (null, ...)
INSERT ... VALUES ('Miles O\'Brien', ...)
```

Comment: I want the sql null :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$variable_name = "NULL";
```

Now, while inserting into the database, use $variable_name.

That should do it.

EDIT: You need to either use prepare statements, if you are gonna switch to PDOs in future or escape the user input.